# velocity template background image spring

Tags: html, spring, velocity

I couldn't able to put bakcground image for the html page which is gennerating by "spring velocity template"..can anyone please help me to do this..

```
my code:::

#macro( IMGURL $imgName )$path/$imgName#end

<html><body>        
 <table background='#IMGURL("Picture2.jpg")'> </table>  
    </body></html>

Thanks,
Manimaran D S
```